# Portugol tem operador ternário?

Tags: if, operadores, visualg, portugol

O Portugol tem algum operador ternário?

Exemplo de como funciona em várias linguagens:

```
algumaVar = 10 > 0 ? 8 : 4
```

Só por curiosidade mesmo, seria interessante se tivesse.

Comment: Acredito eu que não exista e, na minha opinião, nem faz sentido existir. Por mais que o operador ternário seja útil, a ideia do portugol é o ensino de algoritmos para iniciantes. Desta forma, ele sempre dá preferência ao explícito e legível, se aproximando da linguagem natural da pessoa. O operador ternário é facilmente compreendido para quem já tem certa noção de algoritmos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não tem.

Eu revirei as referências do VisualG e não se fala em operadores ternários.

É um pouco questão de opinião, mas acho que faz sentido, uma vez que o portugol é usado apenas pra fins didáticos, então precisa ser legível e compressível e quanto mais explícito, melhor de ler.

Answer (score 2):

Pra afirmar a não existência de algo é preciso ser um profundo conhecedor do assunto, o que não é o meu caso. Mas já muitos materiais sobre Portugol, alguns me pareceram bem completos, e nunca vi nada parecido.

Tem sentido porque esse operador é uma comodidade e em uma linguagem de aprendizado não faz sentido ter algo assim.